# Is it possible to make my phone as a remote shutter?

Tags: camera, photos, remote-control

Is it possible to set a android phone to act as a remote shutter that can connect multiple devices (phones and/or camera) via bluetooth to take photos?

Comment: I don't know any cameras with a Bluetooth shutter interface. Are you sure yours can do this?

Answer (score 1):

These types of remote shutters usually rely on a more standard 3.5mm jack to plug into the camera. The only Bluetooth solution I know of is this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Satechi-Bluetooth-Wireless-EOS-D2000-Compatible/dp/B00ANWQMWK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ANWQMWK)

but unfortunately it looks like its only for Canon DSLRs with a hotshoe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use your android phone to act as a remote shutter for certain digital cameras. Helicon Remote, Remote Release and DslrDashboard  are popular apps that uses USB OTG cable to control various Canon and Nikon DSLRs. EOS Remote is an app from Canon tailormade for its EOS series for DSLRs but it makes of use of wifi though. The only application with description that makes use of both bluetooth and IR to control your camera is DSLR Remote Plus by bitshift. Try the free version available in playstore to check the compatibility with your devices. If satisfied buy the donate version and help the developer.